# Any notification on didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken?

Tags: ios, nsnotificationcenter, nsnotifications

Does iOS trigger a NSNotification (which contains the deviceToken) when didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken is called?

I know I can always save the token in NSUserDefaults from within the AppDelegate and access it anywhere, but I am wondering if there is a better way. I'm thinking something along the lines of UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification.

Update:
The use case if I wanted to get the device token without implementing that delegate method in the AppDelegate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  You will need to implement didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken .  I would imagine one argument against a NSNotification in this situation is that you need to intelligently handle the failure scenarios with didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError.

Comment: I see your point, but it's just that it clutters the AppDelegate. Also, think about the use case where you wanted to register the notification from within a static library that is just dropped in an App that you have no controller over.

Comment: If you are concerned with clutter, simply delegate the call to another class to handle the logic of processing the token.  Actually, you make another argument against the NSNotification in that as an app developer I may not want 3rd party libraries to intercept my user's device tokens.

Comment: Thanks Peter, it sounds like both you and @Subzero are suggesting that there is no easy way to achieve what I was trying.

Answer (score 1):

Could not understand your question properly.

```
 - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application  
didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)devToken
```

This is a method called by the iOS stack (i.e. your application delegate) when the app successfully registers with APNS server thereby obtaining the device token.

(This assumes that you have had your app registered for push notifications by implementing)

```
(void)registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationType)types.
```

In general, one needs to subsequently send this device token to his Push Notification Payload Generating server to register his device with the server. This can be done inside "didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken". Hence I do not really see a need to store the token anywhere. Also, please note that the app registers and obtains the device token from APNS server every time the app launches (not during coming from background to foreground generally- but it depends on your implementation).

Comment: ok. UIApplication class only can call the method registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:. Subsequently, only it's delegate can handle the failure (didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError) or success (didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken) methods since the device stack informs the UIApplication delegate about these. So, I think you can not get away without implementing these methods in your app delegate.